# In-app purchase "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" Xcode 8.3

Tags: xcode, swift3, in-app-purchase

In iPhone I see this data

[image]

and then I get an error  "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".

> Transaction Error: Optional("Cannot connect to iTunes Store")

The code where the error appears

```
private func fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("fail...")
        if let transactionError = transaction.error as? NSError {
            if transactionError.code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
                print("Transaction Error: \(transaction.error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```

Now I check:

- iTunes Connect > Features > In-App Purchases - Approved
- Use real device - Yes
- Connecting to iTunes Sandbox - Yes
- "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" of iTunes Connect - Ok
- iOS Provisioning Profiles - Active (Type:iOS Distribution; Enabled Services: Game Center, In-App Purchase)
- *Sign out* of iCloud on this device - Yes
- Xcode > Capabilities > In-App Purchase - ON (Steps: Link StoreKit.framework - ok; Add the In-App Purchase feature to your App ID - ok)
- delete Apple ID from Xcode and all profiles from /Users/****/Library/MobileDevice and re-uploaded everything
- Use [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial)

Previously everything worked fine (swift 3, Xcode Version 8.2.1)

Comment: @matt, yes. I sign out of iCloud on this device

Comment: Sandbox environment is having issues.

Comment: Apple has fixed the sandbox issues on Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

Today iTunes Sandbox earned, without any changes without any updates. I think yesterday servers were not work. But why Apple can not be told about this so that developers will not do unnecessary work!!!

Comment: Thank you for reporting back. I was going to suggest this same idea, as there were other questions saying much the same thing. Sometimes the store just has troubles.